# Sheets Apps Script filter multiple columns independently of each other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a to do list sheet with a "done" column and a "note type" column and I am attempting to filter each of them independently using apps script.

For example: I want to apply a filter to see only the completed notes of a specific type, OR I want to see only the outstanding notes of a specific type.

The code I have is working, but will not apply both filters at the same time. Running the second filter resets the first.

```
function hideDone() {
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName ) {   
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if(sheet.getRange(1, doneCol,lastRow).getFilter() != null) {
      sheet.getRange(1, doneCol,lastRow).getFilter().remove();
    }
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo("FALSE").build();
    sheet.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(doneCol, criteria);
  }
}
function onlyCue() {
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName ) {   
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    if(sheet.getRange(1, noteTypeCol,lastRow).getFilter() != null) {
      sheet.getRange(1, noteTypeCol,lastRow).getFilter().remove();
    }
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo("CUE").build();
    sheet.getDataRange().createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(noteTypeCol, criteria);
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your functions are organized by column, try modifying the existing [Filter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter) if one exists instead of removing and rebuilding an entirely new one each time.

```
function hideDone() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // added to make code run; not sure if you handle elsewhere

  if(sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName) {   
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var filter = sheet.getRange(1, doneCol, lastRow).getFilter();
    if(filter == null) {
      filter = sheet.getDataRange().createFilter();
    }
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo("FALSE").build();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(doneCol, criteria);
  }
}

function onlyCue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // added to make code run; not sure if you handle elsewhere

  if (sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName) {   
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var filter = sheet.getRange(1, noteTypeCol, lastRow).getFilter();
    if (filter == null) {
      filter = sheet.getDataRange().createFilter();
    }
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo("CUE").build();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(noteTypeCol, criteria);
  }
}
```

If you're worried about situations where data is added below or to the right of the filter range, here's a modification that may work for you:

```
/**
 * Returns a Filter spanning the given sheet's data range while preserving
 * existing filtering criteria on the sheet.
 *
 * @param {Sheet} sheet
 * @return {Filter} filter that spans the given sheet's data range
 */
function getFilterForSheetDataRange_(sheet) {
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  if (filter == null) {
    return dataRange.createFilter();
  }

  var newNumRows = dataRange.getNumRows();
  var newNumColumns = dataRange.getNumColumns();

  var filterRange = filter.getRange();
  var numRows = filterRange.getNumRows();
  var numColumns = filterRange.getNumColumns();

  if (numRows === newNumRows && numColumns === newNumColumns) {
    return filter;
  }

  filter.remove();
  var newFilter = dataRange.createFilter();
  for (var c = 1; c <= numColumns && c <= newNumColumns; c++) {
    newFilter.setColumnFilterCriteria(c, filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(c));
  }

  return newFilter;
}

function hideDone() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // added to make code run; not sure if you handle elsewhere

  if(sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName) {
    var filter = getFilterForSheetDataRange_(sheet);
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo("FALSE").build();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(doneCol, criteria);
  }
}

function onlyCue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // added to make code run; not sure if you handle elsewhere

  if(sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName) {
    var filter = getFilterForSheetDataRange_(sheet);
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo("CUE").build();
    filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(noteTypeCol, criteria);
  }
}
```